# Put data from column table select in varchar variable

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with one column, and I need to put the data from that column in a varchar variable , splited with comma.
exp: 
I have the next table with column organistionIds:

```
    organisationIds

 1. 1000016
 2. 1000017
 3. 1000028
```

How can I put the organisationIds in a varchar variable like:

```
@organisationIds='1000016, 1000017, 1000028'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have it as below:

```
DECLARE @AllOrgIDs VARCHAR(100)


SELECT @AllOrgIDs = COALESCE(@AllOrgIDs + ', ', '') + OrganisationIDs
FROM Yourtable

Select @AllOrgIDs as CommaSeparatedOrgIDs
```